# Getting an error spy method not called, where as i am calling it- ANgular 5 , Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, angular5, angular-test

I have a function as below:

```
saveItinerary() {
    if (this.showAlertModal) {
      this.closeAlertModal();
    }
```

Testing it using jasmine , angular 5:

```
it('to test if alert model closes' , () => {
      spyOn(component, 'closeAlertModal');
      component.showAlertModal = false;
      component.saveItinerary();
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(component.closeAlertModal).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
```

Getting error expected spy closeAlertModal to be called 1 times , but called 0 times.

Comment: `if (this.showAlertModal)` mean if showAlertModal is true then do ... but you set to false  on `component.showAlertModal = false;`

Comment: oh ...what a silly mistake :P... Thanks a lot